# How to copy mongodb server to localhost by given connection string

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodump

My goal is to copy a mongodb server from remote server to my local MacOS machine. I have connection string like this: **mongodb://xxxxxx:yyyyyy@44.444.44.444:27017/?authSource=admin&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl**

Answer (score 1):

1. [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/) from your remote server to your local computer
2. [mongorestore](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongorestore/) from your local computer to your local database